# Getting back nil from Google Translate using Swift and Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, google-translate, alamofire

I am trying to use Alamofire to use the Google Translate api.

Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
    let textToTranslate = "你好"

    let parameters = ["key":"MY_PRIVATE_IOS_APP_KEY","q":"\(textToTranslate)",
        "source":"zh-CN","target":"en"]

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/languages", parameters:parameters)
        .responseJSON
        { (_, _, JSON, _) -> Void in

         let translatedText: String? = JSON?.valueForKeyPath("data") as String?
         println(translatedText)
        }
```

The console keeps printing `nil`.

Also, in the Google Translate API Usage Report it says I have "Client Errors".

This is the kind of output I get when I try this in the browser:

```
{
 "data": {
  "translations": [
   {
    "translatedText": "hello"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The URL that you should GET is:

`https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?parameters`

On your code I see the URL:

`https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/languages?parameters`